# Conditional mocking: Call original function if condition does match

Tags: python, mocking

How can I conditionally call the original method in a mock?

In this example I only want to fake a return value if `bar=='x'`. Otherwise I want to call the original method.

```
def mocked_some_method(bar):
    if bar=='x':
        return 'fake'
    return some_how_call_original_method(bar)

with mock.patch('mylib.foo.some_method', mocked_some_method):
    do_some_stuff()
```

I know that it is a bit strange. If I want to fake `mylib.foo.some_method` in side `do_some_stuff()` it should be condition-less. All (not some) calls to `some_method` should be mocked.

In my case it is an integration test, not a s tiny unittest and `mylib.foo.some_method` is a kind of dispatcher which gets used very often. And in one case I need to fake the result.

## Update

I wrote this question four years ago. Today, it feels very strange to do conditional mocking. Mocks should only get used in tests. Tests (and production code) should be simple and small. Tests should be conditionless. As I wrote this question, we still used huge production methods and long test. Today, I follow these rules (simple methods, conditionless tests ...). I wrote my findings down: [my programming guidelines](https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines/)

Comment: Link [my programming guidelines] is broken.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you need just replace behavior without care of mock's calls assert function you can use `new` argument; otherwise you can use [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) that take a callable.

I guess that `some_method` is a object method (instead of a `staticmethod`) so you need a reference its object to call it. Your wrapper should declare as first argument the object and your patch use `autospec=True` to use the correct signature for `side_effect` case.

Final trick is save the original method reference and use it to make the call.

```
orig = mylib.foo.some_method
def mocked_some_method(self, bar):
    if bar=='x':
        return 'fake'
    return orig(self, bar)

#Just replace:
with mock.patch('mylib.foo.some_method', new=mocked_some_method):
    do_some_stuff()

#Replace by mock
with mock.patch('mylib.foo.some_method', side_effect=mocked_some_method, autospec=True) as mock_some_method:
    do_some_stuff()
    assert mock_some_method.called
```

Comment: What do you mean with "static" here: "I guess that some_method is not static ..."?

Comment: You are right. mock as wrapper is not best practice. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @guettli From your question I can just guess that `some_method` is not `@staticmethod` but an object method.... I'll change my answer by remove the side note but it should already fit your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Returning `unittest.mock.DEFAULT` using return_value or side_effects will call original method. This should allow to avoid some of the wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an example of how you can dynamically patch class method and execute the original method when you need**

1. Code which needs to be tested

```
class CheckMockMethod:

    def get_value_x_10(self, value):
        """Method which is going to be patched"""
        return value*10


def wrapper_func():
    """Function which is called from test"""
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        print(CheckMockMethod().get_value_x_10(i))
```

2. ContextManager test helper for mock.patcher

```
import mock
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def mock_patch_method_original(mock_path, original_method, results):
    results = iter(results)

    def side_effect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = next(results)
        if value == '__original__':
            side_effect.self = self
            return original_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return value

    patcher = mock.patch(mock_path, autospec=True, side_effect=side_effect)
    yield patcher.start()
    patcher.stop()
```

3. Example test method, see the value of results var, `__original__` when you want to return original value

```
    from somewhere import CheckMockMethod
    from test_helpers import mock_patch_method_original


    def test_wrapper(self):
        path = '<import-path>.CheckMockMethod.get_value_x_10'
        orig = CheckMockMethod.get_value_x_10

        results = [1000, '__original__', 3000]

        with mock_patch_method_original(path, original_method=orig, results=results):
            wrapper_func()
```

4. Results

   With mock you will see

> 1000, 20, 3000

where **1000** and **3000** are patched values and **20** is original

Comment: This creates a new instance of CheckMockMethod for the internal call, so any state of the object is ignored, which defeats the purpose of mocking an object

Comment: @polo in the title it is said "patch class method", which always keeps same state

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what to search for to understand your "`side_effect.self = self`" code. Can you please explain it or tell me the keywords to search for so I can read about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good library (I am the author) exactly built for such purpose:
https://github.com/zhukovgreen/pytest-when

Usage example:

```
when(mylib.foo, "some_method").called_with("something").then_return("mocked")
```