# how to mock reader/writing a file

Tags: python-3.x, testing, python-mock

I have a function which looks like this

```
def my_fun(input_csv, output_log, pubusb_project):
  f_in = open(input_csv)
  rows = csv.reader(f_in)
  f_out = open(output_log, 'w')
  # rest of the code including publishing to pubsub topic
  f_in.close()
  f_out.close()
```

How can i test this? I was thinking to use `python-mock` but it looks like that python mock can be used if i pass in actual file object, not the file path.

Is there a way to test this code with python mock? Or do i have to create a temporary file to test it first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in python how to mock only the file write but not the file read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617202/in-python-how-to-mock-only-the-file-write-but-not-the-file-read)

Comment: Looks like it does but I am not an expert at python so not sure how to apply for my code. Also does it use pytest? Because I have to use pytest