# Python Patch/Mock class method but still call original method

Tags: python, mocking

I want to use patch to record all function calls made to a function in a class for a unittest, but need the original function to still run as expected. I created a dummy code example below:

```
from mock import patch

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__() # TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not MagicMock
        self._b = 11

    def bar(self, b):
        self._b = self._b + 1 + b

    def foo(self, b):
        self.bar(b)

class MockB(B):
    def foo(self, b):
        super(MockB, self).foo(self, b)

@patch('main.B')
def main(b_class):
    b_class.side_effect = MockB

    b = B()

    print b._b # 11
    b.foo(0)
    print b._b # 12

main()
```

In my case, the instance of the class `b = B()` is not actually in the main function but in another module, so I can't Mock the instance. I need it to generically be a decorator for all instances of B.

Summary: I am not sure how to individually mock the class method on it's own, but still call the original method. After, I want to use something like [call_args_list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) where I can see all calls made to `foo()`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, what's actually under test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks it wasn't relevant. I have removed the tag.

Comment: What's not relevant? If you're not testing, why are you mocking anything?

Comment: The relevant part is that I need to mock a class method and keep the original method working. I want to mock because it comes with call_args_list and other useful functionality.

Comment: See also [python mock - patching a method without obstructing implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25608107/1048572) and [How to mock in python and still allow the actual code of mocked function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36717312/1048572)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `wraps` Mock parameter. Search the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) for `wraps`. Accessing attributes returns a mock object. Calling methods gives the real method result instead, if a return value is not configured for the mock.

Comment: A code snippet with an example wouldn't hurt. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724642/8843585

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to, e.g., `mock.patch('os.remove', wraps=os.remove)`. This way, I have mock with which I can call `assert_called_once_with()`, etc., and `os.remove()` still gets called as is.

Answer (score 4):

More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963740/1731460

```
import mock
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def mock_patch_method_original(mock_path, original_method, results):
    results = iter(results)

    def side_effect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = next(results)
        if value == '__original__':
            side_effect.self = self
            return original_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return value

    patcher = mock.patch(mock_path, autospec=True, side_effect=side_effect)
    yield patcher.start()
    patcher.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just keep a reference to your original, non-mocked/patched instance around.

I had an issue that I was patching `ctypes.windll.winmm.mciSendStringW`, but I still wanted to be able to access that original function. Initially, I had tried:

```
from ctypes import windll
originalWindll = windll

# Later on trying to call the original mciSendStringW when it's patched...
originalWindll.winmm.mciSendStringW(...)  # Didn't work! Called the patched version of the function!
```

The correct thing to do was actually this... since it was the function being mocked/patched, it was the function that I needed to keep a reference to.

```
from ctypes import windll
originalMCISendStringW = windll.winmm.mciSendStringW

# Later on trying to call the original mciSendStringW when it's patched...
originalMCISendStringW(...)  # Works! Calls the original, non-patched version of this function!
```