# How do you watch a callable object's arguments and return values?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a Python object and I want to know what args, kwargs, and return values it made. The solution should be something like this.

```py
class Fizz(object):
    def do_something(self, item, blah=8):
        return "done"


buzz = Fizz()

with watch(buzz.do_something) as container:
    buzz.do_something("asdf")
    buzz.do_something("another", blah=10)

container  # [(("asdf", ), dict(), "done"), (("another", ), {"blah": 10}, "done")]
```

So the key points are

- Able to watch args, kwargs, and return values
- Is temporary (I can decide when and how to watch and when to un-watch)
- Ideally, this should work with instance objects. But at minimum, it needs to be able to at least work with class, method, and function definitions (like how [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) does it).

### Similar Things That Already Exist

[mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) allows you to watch arguments but, as far as I know, it replaces the class / function / method. The original callable object does not get called, which is not what I want. I want the original to still be called while also keeping track of what's passed in and out of the callable object.

Maybe there's a way to make mock do what I need it to do or some other existing library? Anyone know of anything?

Comment: I think this is relevant.  You want to mock a method, but still be able to call the original method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562460/conditional-mocking-call-original-function-if-condition-does-match/61963740#61963740

Comment: This looks really good. Didn't know that you could use the original callable as a side effect. Thanks for your quick reply!